# Django serve file in memory instead of saving on disk

Tags: python, django, matplotlib, django-rest-framework

I want to render plot (`matplotlib`) in one place of code and then in `ViewSet` serve to it user without saving on disk. I tried to use `io` library to keep file in memory, but it seems that always something is wrong.

My code where I save plot on disk:

```
def some_func(self):
    ...generating plot...
    
    filename = self.generate_path()  # generate random name for file
    plt.savefig(filename, transparent=True)
    return filename
```

Code of `ViewSet`:

```
class SomeViewsSet(ViewSet):

    def create(self, request):
            ... some code ...

            path = some_func()
            name = path.split('/')[-1]
            with open(path, 'rb') as file:
                response = HttpResponse(file, content_type=guess_type(path)[0])
                response['Content-Length'] = len(response.content)
                response['Content-Disposition'] = f'attachment; filename={name}'
                return response
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure that you pass matplotlib a [`BytesIO`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.BytesIO) object, and not a `StringIO`. Then get the bytes using `getvalue()`, and pass them to `HttpResponse`. If that's what you've already tried, please post your code and the error message you're seeing.

Comment: It worked, thank you. I tried yesterday use `open` function  what was a mistake.